# Round float in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I have a problem with float in Python...

I have this in a variable:

```
i = 9.600000000000001
```

And I would transform in this:

```
i = 9.60000
```

with five numbers after the decimal point and rounded.

Comment: Do you want to output the float or round the value itself? For the latter, it cannot be accomplished for most values due to the nature of floats. Research on your own to know why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> format(9.60000001,'.5f')                                                                                                            
'9.60000'
>>>
```

Comment: sorry, I just wanna show the method

Answer (score 1):

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 6
i = 9.600000000000001
newI = Decimal(i)/1

print(newI)
```

returns 9.60000.  However, float(newI) return 9.6, which is correct.  The real question is do you want the actual value, in which case 9.60000 = 9.6, or just display 9.6 as 9.60000?  In that case, the print solutions above will get you there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the second parameter in the round() function.

```
i = 9.600000000000001
i = round(i, 5)
print("%.5f" % i)
```

will return 9.60000.